# Publish a win message on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a button on my app when the user finish the game, he can public in the facebook, somebody can help me? I have this code but it's for publishing the app on facebook don't know if it works either:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "texte");
myIntent.setType("text/plain");

myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It gives all the application list which have sharing feature available.You can also optimize it for facebook only by selecting facebook intent in `createChooser()`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with:"));
```

Comment: I can write a mensage and the user can change it?

Comment: I just want the facebook and i try this: `startActivity(Intent.facebook(intent, "Share with:"));` but dont work

Comment: I can link the app but the ´shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "game complet");´ dont show

Comment: I think Facebook discontinued to use `android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`.They are forcing the developer to use their SDK.